# When I applied RandomForest in Python, ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2883, 1236]

Tags: python-3.x

1. File `"D:\Users\Watson Rockstar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py"`, line 205, in check_consistent_length
   " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
2. ValueError:

   Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2883, 1236]

This dataset totally has 4119 data, and the Xtrain volum=  (2883,18), Xtest volum = (1236,18)

I have tried to use LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder to sovle the problems, but it is not helpful:

```
# Ignore  the warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('always')
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# data visualisation and manipulation
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import seaborn as sns
import missingno as msno

#configure
# sets matplotlib to inline and displays graphs below the corressponding cell.


#import the necessary modelling algos.

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

#preprocessing

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


telebanking = pd.read_csv('bank-additional.csv')
telebank = telebanking.drop(['duration','default'],axis =1)



def transform(feature):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    telebank[feature] = le.fit_transform(telebank[feature])
    print(le.classes_)
    
cat_telebank=telebank.select_dtypes(include='object')
cat_telebank.columns    

for col in cat_telebank.columns:
    transform(col)
    
scaler=StandardScaler()
scaled_telebank=scaler.fit_transform(telebank.drop('y',axis=1))
X=scaled_telebank
Y=telebank['y'].as_matrix()
   

Xtrain,Xtest,Ytrain,Ytest = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.3)

def compare(model):
    clf = model
    clf.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain)
    pred = clf.predict(Xtrain)
    
    acc.append(accuracy_score(pred,Ytest))
    prec.append(precision_score(pred,Ytest))
    rec.append(recall_score(pred,Ytest))
    auroc.append(roc_auc_score(pred,Ytest))
 
acc=[]
prec=[]
rec=[]
auroc=[]
models=[RandomForestClassifier(),DecisionTreeClassifier()]
model_names=['RandomForestClassifier','DecisionTreeClassifier']

for model in range(len(models)):
    compare(models[model])
    
d={'Modelling Algo':model_names,'Accuracy':acc,'Precision':prec,'Recall':rec,'Area Under ROC Curve':auroc}
met_telebank=pd.DataFrame(d)
met_telebank
```

[It is the first warning's detail.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdadZ.png)

Comment: What's the exact question?

Answer (score 0):

```
Xtrain,Xtest,Ytrain,Ytest = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.3)
```

should be

```
Xtrain,Ytrain,Xtest,Ytest = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.3)
```

This is causing the error, because it wants to use `Xtest` as the `Ytrain` values.